# WHERE NOT EXISTS Query Not Working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find out if there are any orders in the inventory_detail table (the order number is actually on inventory_header) where either the load_store OR the unload_store value does not exist at all in the store_Code field in extrainfo_stores table.

The query below returns some orders where, when I look in the extrainfo_stores table for a order returned, I see the exact value that is in load_store or unload_store in that table, so it's obviously not working...

```
 SELECT  bh.ord_number, bi.*
 FROM    inventory_header bh
 inner join inventory_detail bi on inventory_id = bh.inventory_id
 WHERE   NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT  null 
    FROM    extrainfo_stores d
    WHERE   d.ord_number = bh.ord_number
      and   bi.load_store <> d.store_code
      and   bi.unload_store <> d.store_code
    )
```

Comment: Why use SELECT NULL? Every exists check I have ever seen uses "SELECT *" or "SELECT 1".

Comment: @StingyJack It doesn't make a difference at all. Some people use `SELECT NULL` on `EXISTS` to make it clear that they are not actually retrieving any data (though I prefer `SELECT 1`)

Comment: "select null" will work in an EXIST statement because the EXIST statement returns true if there is at least one record in the result set. A result set with one record whose only field is "null" is still a result set, thus EXIST will return true.

Comment: If you you to know if either is not present then why the and condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like:

```
SELECT bh.ord_number, bi.*
  FROM inventory_header bh
 inner join inventory_detail bi on inventory_id = bh.inventory_id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null 
                     FROM extrainfo_stores d
                    WHERE d.ord_number = bh.ord_number
                      and (bi.load_store = d.store_code or bi.unload_store = d.store_code))
```

Comment: This was perfect. I guess the wrong way to go was to not exclude the excluded and to group the either two conditions. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT bh.ord_number, bi.*
 FROM  inventory_header bh
 join  inventory_detail bi 
   on  inventory_id = bh.inventory_id
 join  extrainfo_stores d
   on  d.ord_number = bh.ord_number
Where bi.load_store   <> d.store_code
   or bi.unload_store <> d.store_code
```